# Clicking a question that has duplicate results in redirection to the duplicate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions

Clicking the link to this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004666/get-rid-of-warnings-in-ruby) in a list (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) results in skipping the target page, and silently redirects to the duplicate page ([Erroneous "Insecure world writable dir foo in PATH" when running ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708806/erroneous-insecure-world-writable-dir-foo-in-path-when-running-ruby-script)).

<strike>I observed this on Safari on iOS. I checked that this does not happen on Chrome on Linux.</strike> This sometimes happens, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an anonymous user visits a question closed as a duplicate with no answers, they are automatically redirected to the duplicate question.

Logged in / registered users are not automatically redirected.

Anonymous users who really want to see the original question can access it by appending `?noredirect=1` to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was careless. Sorry about that.

Comment: I know this is by design, but it's confusing/annoying to click on a link in the "Related" sidebar and appear to go nowhere (because it redirects to the page I'm currently on).  (Though I don't care enough to make a formal feature request -- [minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) and all that.)