# Why are duplicate answers deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators, duplicate-answers

I found a frustrating issue today and after one hour I found a solution. There was no answer on Stack Overflow. I then identified 5 similar questions asking about exactly the same problem. I answered them all the same.

All but one of these answers were deleted by the moderator.

I think there are a number of problems with this.

1. Duplicate answers are useful. Sometimes the same solution solves multiple problems. This problem related to using cURL on a newer version PHP. The same problem would arise irrespective of which program was using cURL. The same answer solved multiple different questions. Having the solution to a problem in more places is always more useful than not.
2. There's no way to challenge the decision by the moderator.
3. The moderator just deleted the answers at random rather than leaving the answer to the question with the most views.
4. I spent some of my valuable time to help other people and the answers were just shut down. I contributed to Stack Overflow for free and had my time wasted. This makes me less likely to try to help in the future.

Is there any actual harm that's caused by having a correct solution posted in multiple places?

**Update:**

People have suggested that there are some duplicates to this question. But I'm specifically talking about this situation:

Question 1 - What is 2 + 2
Question 2 - What is 8 - 4

These two questions aren't duplicates. They are two different questions with the same answer.

**For example:**

Here are the questions that I'm actually talking about:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351052/ssl-certificate-error/39957296)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383043/curl-ssl-certificate-error-verifcation-failed/39957324)

These are the same error caused in two different situations with the same solution.

None of the existing answers helped me and none of them really seemed like best practice. I think installing OpenSSL is a better solution than copying a certificate from some other location.

Should these be marked as duplicate?
Should I create a new question and answer it myself?
Should I have just answered the second one with a link to my answer on the first?

I can understand why duplication is bad but I can't see the logic in deleting some valid answers and then not marking the questions as duplicates. In the end, we just have a number of similar questions without any good answers...

The purpose of this question is to try to understand how to handle this situation next time in a way that will be most helpful to the community.

Comment: You should have voted to close the questions as duplicates if you honestly feel that they're answered by an identical answer.  You would have been told as much by the moderator when your posts were deleted.

Comment: "There's no way to challenge the decision by the moderator" You just did.

Comment: I think this is a different situation - it's two different questions by two different users with the same solution. See update.

Comment: When you've been looking for a hammer for a while, and finally found one, then everything starts to look like a nail.  The one that's left asked "how to get a certificate authority to trust me" and you hammered with "here's how to add a certificate".  You only hit your thumb.

Comment: Oh the irony...

Comment: your question regarding a duplicate turns out to be a  DUPLICATE.... Hilarious??

Answer (score 32):

Note that ♦ moderators are automatically warned if somebody posts the same answer to multiple questions.

> 1. Duplicate answers are useful.
>
> Is there any actual harm that's caused by having a correct solution posted in multiple places?

The reason for not allowing duplicate answers is the same as why you shouldn't have duplicated code in your project: [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If your answer becomes outdated, or you want to add/change some information for any other reason, you need to do it in five places. It's better to have the questions be marked as duplicates of each other; if an anonymous user visits a question which is marked as a duplicate and has *no answers*, he/she is [automatically redirected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311459/clicking-a-question-that-has-duplicate-results-in-redirection-to-the-duplicate/311460#311460) to the duplicate target. Most of the Stack Overflow traffic comes from Google and other search engines, and those people greatly benefit from the duplicate system as it works currently.

> 2. There's no way to challenge the decision by the moderator.

As [@Yannis notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336000/why-are-duplicate-answers-deleted/336001#comment403111_336000), you just did. But Meta seems to disagree with you.

> 3. The moderator just deleted the answers at random rather than leaving the answer to the question with the most views.

If you had posted your answer only to the question with the most views, this wouldn't have happened.

> 4. I spent some of my valuable time to help other people and the answers were just shut down.

Copying and pasting answers doesn't cost time, at least not when compared to *writing* a good answer.

Comment: It's strange that people down vote this question. I don't think it's an unreasonable question to ask. The whole experience makes me feel that StackOverflow is a bit of a toxic community which is sad.

Comment: @BenSmiley it's pretty established on meta that we delete duplicate answers and WHY. So your question comes a bit as an unresearched one, which may explain the downvotes. On top of it, you sound a bit ranty in your post, which is a sure way to get downvotes on meta. + you come in with a couple of wrong assumptions. One question downvotes != toxic. Stop taking votes personally... they rate your post, no you...

Comment: @BenSmiley The moderator who deleted your posts *already provided you all of this information*.  You simply couldn't be bothered to read the comment on your deleted post.  Posting a meta question just so other people can repeat the same information for you is not helpful; the votes are reflecting that.