# Why was my answer deleted with the reason "Don't post identical answers to multiple questions"?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

Two questions were asked in the past, both of them wanted to detect user touch on the Google map:

- [How to handle touch event on google map (MapFragment)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281211/how-to-handle-touch-event-on-google-map-mapfragment)
- [Google Maps Android API v2 - detect touch on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map)

To achieve this in the past, we needed to so much workaround, but since last August the good people in Google provided a standard way to do this. I added a new answer to both questions indicating that this issue was solved now and I even included a code snippet from the official Google documentation.

This morning I was surprised that my answer was deleted from one of the questions with the reason "Don't post identical answers to multiple questions" although this answer is correct (and up-to-date) for both of them.

I think that it is unfair that my answer was deleted. If these question were really identical, I think it is more appropriate to leave my answer and close one of them and mark the question as duplicate. Leaving my answer there would help anyone redirected there.

Comment: If they are identical questions, you shouldn't be giving the same answer to both but vote to close them as duplicates and leave **one** answer only on one of them.

Comment: In the two links i provided, the first one contained my deleted answer , while the second one contain the answer that wasnt deleted , i still dont know why I am being downvoted , although i asked legitimate question and got an answer

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336000/why-are-duplicate-answers-deleted?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers - _"Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: .... exact duplicates of other answers"_ That's why I down voted, you've done no research.

Comment: Meta help  http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta  describes how people should vote. meta votes have no meaning in a discussion post. Some are upvoting a useful question, if they are inexperienced in meta culture, and then there is incorrect voting to indicate agreement/disagreement.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617 The powers that be are powerless but may remain hopeful as the whats meta help topic has not been changed.

Comment: First check if they are duplicate questions. If so, answer only one and flag the other as duplicate, if not you can answer both (with the same answer if the answers are answering the non-duplicate questions). So the real question is: Are they duplicates? Bear in mind that having identical answers is a very strong hint that they might be duplicates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should never post exactly the same answer to two different questions.

If two questions can be fully and completly answered by the same exact answer, they are duplicates, and should be closed as such. In this case, I have voted to close [How to handle touch event on google map (MapFragment)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281211/how-to-handle-touch-event-on-google-map-mapfragment) as a duplicate of [Google Maps Android API v2 - detect touch on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map) .

If two questions can not be answered by the same answer, then you shouldn't post the same answer to them.

Comment: Except when it's a virtualbox issue, and it's solved by installed guest additions... the thing is a swiss knife.