# How to answer similar questions relating to a service outage

Tags: discussion

Currently the twitter streaming API is experiencing issues, as reported on the twitter developers forum: https://twittercommunity.com/t/issues-reported-with-streams-since-10-21/76429/8. Connections are getting dropped after very short periods of time, sometimes in the middle of transmitting data, resulting in various errors.

This has resulted in a number of similar, but distinct questions where people have experienced related problems caused by the outage, but they are not duplicates of each other.

What is the correct way of dealing with these questions? The questions have temporary value, as it is clearly useful to inform people that the service is not working , and they are not exact duplicates, but, the answers are duplicates, and the information will become outdated once the service is fixed.

I have already provided nearly identical answers to three of these questions:

[Cannot use GetStreamSample method in python-twitter package on the cloud(ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232745/cannot-use-getstreamsample-method-in-python-twitter-package-on-the-cloudubuntu)

[tweets live streaming using tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230330/tweets-live-streaming-using-tweepy)

[Stream is closing in twitter4j (Hadoop- flume)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207141/stream-is-closing-in-twitter4j-hadoop-flume)

Comment: Its also important to ask what not to do; posting the same answer multiple times is on the [no-no list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336883/424903).